# Shimano Roller Brake Model BR-IM31 (specifically!!)

Tags: innertube, puncture, cargo, roller-brake

New to the world of roller brakes (new cargo bike) and need to change back inner tube due to flat.

I'm trying to work out how to remove the back wheel and have unclipped the gear cable (nexus hub) but the roller brake (IM31) seems not to be 'unclippable'... there are various youtube videos of flicking a nut out of the body of the roller brake for other brake models, or unclipping it from the brake arm - but neither of these seem possible on my model..

I'm wondering if the only option to remove it is to loosen off the cable fixing nut - which would require re-securing and readjusting the cable each and every time the wheel is removed...

Anyone have any experience with this?!

this is model:
https://bike.shimano.com/en-NZ/product/component/shimano/BR-IM31-F.html

and this (page 21)-
https://resources.chainbox.io/2/cykelpartner/public/pim/52f4531a-38aa-4201-b92f-44a11f8e9bd9/EBRIM31RFE_A.pdf

....and if it is such a hassle to remove the wheel each time - any suggestions for puncture-proofing - I have shwalbe big apple tires - and thinking about some sort of puncture resistant slime to put in inner tube (or similar)...

Thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: Usually it's possible to leave a cable like that connected when changing an inner tube .. if there's enough free cablerun you can unclip from the frame and you're working out of a repair stand

Comment: Thanks - will try this weekend - much appreciated